# Cannot Add Images to Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, image, imageview

I am currently having issues adding images to Xcode, it shows the under the file tab the option of adding files is unavailable. Even before I could drag and drop images into Xcode on the left side with all other files in the project but now it doesn’t allow me to do so. Greatly appreciate anyones help :)

Comment: Have you tried dragging them to the xcassets folder?

Comment: Hi @Magnas thanks for getting back to me, I tired this and it did work but I can see the image come up in Image View. It still shows “?”

Comment: Got it working now. Thank for your help!

Comment: @Magnas how can I mark your comment as helpful? Sorry only new to this

Comment: The little 'up' triangle above the flag to the left of the comment. Welcome to SO BTW.

Comment: I tired that but I’m getting a message saying “Request failed: You cannot vote for this comment” @Magnas

Comment: @Jake.mangubat You are not capable to vote comments yet. Magnas has to post it as an answer for you to mark it as Correct.